# How can I debug a link function in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, angularjs-directive, google-chrome-devtools

How can I debug the link function in a directive?

The debugger does not stop at `debugger;` in the code below. A breakpoint in Chrome also does not work.

```
fessmodule.directive('dummy', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {  
        debugger;
        scope.data = scope.data + " + directive postfix";    
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: do you actually call your directive in your DOM?

Comment: +1 directive link are totally debuggable, your problem is somewhere else. Do you really have a `<div dummy></div>` somewhere ?

Comment: Thx for your help. The problem was somewhere else. Manually bootstrapping did not add some directives.

Comment: directives can be debugged via chrome. But you should call it on your html. Make sure you call it on the right place.

Comment: I had a similar problem today and realized that I was trying to debug a directive that I was no longer using so it never got called.